# Adding destination email to contact form

Tags: html, css

I have a [contact form at codepen.io](http://codepen.io/markmurray/pen/JsAhx), but it is not working. I don't know where I must put the email address that messages will be sent to.

```
<form class="cf">
  <div class="half left cf">
    <input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address">
    <input type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject">
  </div>
  <div class="half right cf">
    <textarea name="message" type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you need to have a php send mail form too, also edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste your code because almost everyone will not go to your link, you didn't even make a clickable link

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: google is your friend, http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/sending-email-from-site/using-the-php-mail-function-to-send-emails

Comment: Linking to the codepen in your question will help users see through your intent. Also, consider posting relevant code with your question. The more you help other users understand your question, the more likely they are to answer it precisely.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a really basic form to send an email, you can set the form action to "mailto:user@email.com". This will open the users default mail client and populate the subject and body with the contents of inputs named "subject" and "body" in the form. The form itself won't send email though - you would need PHP for that.

Comment: Yes I know that and I add this but beside of this I want a simple form for asking name, email and message. this is for job vacancies

Comment: To have the form itself send email, you need to use PHP. HTML alone won't send an email.

Comment: Okay I added PHP code but why every time I hit send browser try to open the PHP file?

Comment: You need to post the code you have. Are you hosting this on a server that has PHP installed?

Comment: @user3003580 PHP is a server side language and requires a server that will process your php file. If you see the php as text then your php engine is not configured properly